# C# and LDAPs other than MSAD

Tags: c#, ldap

Is there a way for a C# application to interact via LDAP with directory servers like Sun's or Tivoli's ? If it's possible, any hints you can give me?

Comment: Application code should not be written with knowledge of a particular server. The resulting code is brittle and fragile. Application code dealing with LDAP servers should be written to adhere to LDAP standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace contains various generic LDAP classes e.g. System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection